# How can I use the evaluation metric of R squared in XGBoost.cv?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I employ the following code for some reason, but there is no evaluation metric of R squared in XGBoost.cv. Is there a way to use R squared at the same time as RMSE?

`cv_results = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=800, seed=42, nfold=5, metrics=['rmse'], early_stopping_rounds=10)`